# Angular 2 raising events in nested components

Tags: events, angular

This is a slightly subjective question but I would like to gather some opinions to check if my thinking is correct.

When raising events from nested components, at what point is a MessageBus approach preferable to bubbling the events?

Take the following example, where the user can select to delete a card from a grid:

[image: card layout example with 4 cards, all have X buttons for deletion]

If we take the layout of this as:

```
grid.component    
├── card.component
│   ├── image.component
│   ├── text.component
│   ├── closebutton.component
```

If I wanted to handle that closebutton clicked event up in the grid component, I would need to bubble the event from the close through the card, and then to grid (NOTE: this isn't an awfully complicated example of this, but I wanted it to be easily followed).

Alternatively, I could implement something like a MessageBus as a singleton/provider to my components which could raise and listen for messages. I could fire a close event from the "X" button and listen for it at the top of the tree. This means I wouldn't have to worry about chaining events together, and keep the layout cleaner.

What are the pros and cons to each approach here?

EDIT: I see close votes based on the "opinion-based" question; but I would like to direct answers toward the pros vs cons of each approach here, rather than advising on preferred options. Thanks!

EDIT 2: Contrary to my own feelings (and those expressed in the comments), I've happened upon [this in the Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) which seems to imply that the Messaging service is a supported option...

Comment: Bubbling events is the preferred way AFAIAC. It might be more work to do this but it's all about consistency in your approach. The smart vs dumb paradigm was created for several reasons and if you break it here, you'll quite possibly regret it in the near future (believe me, I've been there). Bubbling events is the way to go.

Comment: @KwintenP Thanks for your input! I was thinking the same - I've written up MessageBus designs in the past but I'm always worried about it being overused/misused by the next person to come along and work on the feature area.

Comment: My pleasure. It's basically the same discussion I have with every one that starts working with smart and dumb components. Consistency is key.